# Static files do not show up in the Django app

Tags: django, apache, static, django-staticfiles

I have a problem with static files in django. The application appears, but there is no static files.
I made collecstatic command.

I'm using apache, below is a virtual host sites-available directory

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myapp.example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/prod/www/myapp/myapp
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"

        # Django statics, MEDIA_URL
        Alias /media/ /home/prod/www/myapp/myapp/MyBlog/media
        Alias /static/ /home/prod/www/myapp/myapp/staticfiles

        <Directory /home/prod/www/myapp/myapp>
            Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
            AllowOverride AuthConfig
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
            ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 day"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day"
            ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 day"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day"
            ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 day"
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        RewriteRule ^/media/.* - [L]
        RewriteRule ^/static/.* - [L]
        #RewriteRule ^/favicon\.ico - [L]

        RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1:48036$1 [P]

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

When I execute `print STATIC_ROOT` I get:

```
 /home/prod/www/myapp/myapp/staticfiles
```

My static url sets on:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your conf

```
<Directory /home/prod/www/myapp/myapp/staticfiles>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Not working with this settings. Maybe help this, my url: `http://myapp.exaple.com/static/js/bootstrap.js`

Comment: Is there anything in `/home/prod/www/myapp/myapp/staticfiles` ?

Comment: Specifically in the js dir underneath.

Comment: That's helpful because you aren't getting a 403 unauthorized. can you please show an `ls` of that dir?

Comment: @C.B. My staticfiles dir: `admin  css  debug_toolbar  fonts  images  js  sass`